# What does sorting a list of lists in python mean for the following example:

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
>> L = [[9, 1], [3, 4]]

>> sorted(L, key=lambda x:x[0])

[[3,4], [9,1]]
```

The above will sort the list according to the first element, meaning that the list with the smallest first element will appear first.

However, what does the following mean?

```
>> L = [[9, 1], [3, 4]]

>> sorted(L, key=lambda x:(x[0], x[1]))

[[3,4], [9,1]]
```

Or even

```
>> L = [[9, 1], [3, 4]]

>> sorted(L, key=lambda x:(x[0], x[1], x[0]))

[[3,4], [9,1]]
```

I'm not sure what keys mean when they have more than one item.

Comment: if the first element is the same, it goes by the second (and so on)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this makes it clear:

```
>>> L
[[9, 1], [3, 4], [3, 2], [9, 0]]
>>> sorted(L, key=lambda x:(x[0], x[1]))
[[3, 2], [3, 4], [9, 0], [9, 1]]
```

Sort by first and then second element of the sublist.